# How to add and use an existing SQLite database(x.db) using Coredata?

Tags: iphone, ios, sqlite, core-data

In my project, I am using CoreData to create and use database, it is working perfectly fine. Now I have an SQLite database file(.db) which I want to integrate into my project and use it (using coredata).

I have added the .db file into my project and have created writable copy of it in Documents directory using the following code -:

```
- (void)createEditableCopyOfDatabaseIfNeeded {
// First, test for existence.
BOOL success;
NSFileManager *fileManager = [NSFileManager defaultManager];
NSError *error;
NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
NSString *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
NSString *writableDBPath = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"wordlist1000.db"];
success = [fileManager fileExistsAtPath:writableDBPath];
if (success)
    return;
// The writable database does not exist, so copy the default to the appropriate location.
NSString *defaultDBPath = [[[NSBundle mainBundle] resourcePath] stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"wordlist1000.db"];
success = [fileManager copyItemAtPath:defaultDBPath toPath:writableDBPath error:&error];
if (!success) {
    NSAssert1(0, @"Failed to create writable database file with message '%@'.", [error localizedDescription]);
}
```

}

Now when I try to fetch results from database I get this error

> SQLite error code:1, 'no such table: Z_METADATA', NSSQLiteErrorDomain=1}

Kindly tell me how to proceed from here. Some code samples would be of great help.

**To summarise, I just want to import an external database and use it in my xCode project using CoreData.**

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

You can't do that. Core Data is not a simple wrapper for SQLite. It presents a very different API and uses its own, undocumented SQLite schema. SQLite is an implementation detail, not something you can use directly via Core Data.

If you want to get your SQLite data into Core Data, you'll need to:

1. Add a Core Data model file to your project and configure it to contain the appropriate entities to match your schema.
2. Read the data from SQLite using either its own native API or one of the Objective-C wrappers like FMDB or PLDatabase.
3. Write that data to a new Core Data store file using Core Data's API.

You might just want to leave the data in SQLite. FMDB and PLDatabase provide very convenient wrappers which let you continue to use SQL-isms in your code instead of switching to the Core Data approach.

Answer (score 1):

The way core data store the data in sqlite is different from the way you are storing. Core data creates additional tables to keep information about your entities. So you sqlite db must be same so that there won't be any issues in operations.

Just follow [**`Ray Wenderlich's great Core Data Tutorial: How To Preload/Import Existing Data`**](http://www.raywenderlich.com/980/core-data-tutorial-how-to-preloadimport-existing-data)